Reading a data block from I²C on a Raspberry Pi using Python SMBus2 suddenly quit working. What could be wrong?
I am working on an application transferring data from an Arduino (slave) to a Raspberry Pi (master) over an I²C bus.  I was in the middle of writing the code, when suddenly the transfer quit working, and I cannot figure out why.  I tried re-installing SMBus2, but the problem persists.
Here is some test code, attempting the transfer of 7 bytes from the Arduino:
#! /usr/bin/python3

from smbus2 import SMBus

slaveAddress = 10
blockSize = 7

with SMBus(1) as bus:
    # Read a block of blockSize bytes from address slaveAddres, offset 0
    block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(slaveAddress, 0, blockSize)
    # Returned value is a list of slaveAddress bytes
    print(block)

I have tried several variations, but no matter what I get the following:
[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]

If I issue the command
i2ctransfer -y 1 r7@0x0a

I get an expected result similar to:
0x32 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00

Which means the code on the Arduino and the I²C bus are behaving as expected.  What can be wrong and how can I fix it?
EDIT: I tried reading one byte at a time:
#! /usr/bin/python3
from smbus2 import SMBus

slaveAddress = 0x0a
blockSize = 7
block = []
with SMBus(1) as bus:
    for x in range(blockSize):
        block.append(bus.read_byte_data(slaveAddress, x))
print(block)

I still get:
[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]

EDIT 2:  Adding the related code running on the Arduino
#include <Wire.h>

#define Cool    0   // Peltier Cooler ON = HIGH
#define POK 1   // Power Failure IN
#define Fan 9   // Fan Relay ON = HIGH
#define PiCtl   14  // Raspberry Pi Power
#define ADDR1   15  // I2C Address 1
#define ADDR2   16  // I2C Address 2
#define SCL 23  // I2C Clock
#define SDA 24  // I2C Data

#define PTC 13  // Thermocouple Analog IN

int I2C;
bool True = 1;
bool False = 0;
float Temp;
bool FanSet;
bool PowerFail;
bool Responded;
unsigned long TimeStamp;

union Response {
    struct {
        int Temperature;    // 2 bytes
        unsigned long Living;   // 4 bytes
        uint8_t Command;    // 1 byte
        uint8_t FanValue;   // 1 byte
        uint8_t CoolStat;   // 1 byte
        uint8_t PowerStat;  // 1 byte
        uint8_t padding;    // 1 byte
    };
    uint8_t bytes[11];
};
union Response Reply;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(ADDR1, INPUT_PULLUP);   // Address Offset 0 or 1
    pinMode(ADDR2, INPUT_PULLUP);   // Address Offset 0 or 2
    I2C = (2 * digitalRead(ADDR2)) + digitalRead(ADDR1) + 8;    // Set I2C address 8 - 11
    Wire.begin(I2C);        // Initialize I2C Communications
    Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);   // Call requestEvent when data requested
    Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);   // Call receiveEvent when data received
    Reply.PowerStat = 1;        // Reset Power Status
    Reply.FanValue = 1;     // Set Fan Status On
    Reply.CoolStat = 0;     // Set Cool Status Off
}

void TempCheck()
{
    Reply.Temperature = analogRead(PTC);
}

void PowerCheck()
{
    bool Power = digitalRead(POK);
    if (Power)
    {
        if (PowerFail)
        {
            PowerFail = False;  // Reset Power Failure Variable
        }
        Reply.Command = 1;      // Reset shutdown command
        Reply.PowerStat = 1;        // Reset Power Status
    }
    else
    {
        TimeStamp = millis();       // Reset Timer
        int Iterations = 0;     // Reset Time Counter
        Reply.PowerStat = 0;        // Set Power Status
        Reply.Command = 1;
    }
}

// Function that executes whenever data is requested from master
void requestEvent()
{
    Wire.write(Reply.bytes, sizeof Reply);  // respond with message as expected by master
    Responded = True;           // Set the responded variable
    Reply.Living = millis();        // Set the responded time
}

void loop()
{
    PowerCheck();
    TempCheck();
    delay (2000);
}


Try reading the data byte by byte with the 'read_byte_data' method.

That also returns a value of 0xFF for every read.

Have you had enough space in /tmp or other folders that Python may use?

what code is running on the Arduino? Have you considered that the fault might not be in the python code on the raspberry pi but on the Arduino side?

@0andriy  There is plenty of space on the Raspberry Pi.  The directories /tmp, /var, /var/run, /var/tmp, /dev/, /dev/shm, and /run/user/0 are all on separate temporary file systems with between 43 Megs and 183 Megs total space.  The directory /run/user/0 is 5 Megs.  The maximum usage of any of these is currently 1% (684 K).  The root directory has 7.8 Gigs available.  The host is headless, so no GUI is running.  271 Mi out of 429 Mi of memory is available.

@draufunddran The fact i2ctransfer is returning data that is sensible and accurate pretty much rules out an issue with the code on the Arduino.  What's more, the code on the Arduino has not changed since prior to the time when the Python code quit working.  I will go ahead and post the pertinent Arduin code, however.

@LeslieRhorer you are right sorry... i missed the part with the working i2ctransfer. Do you by chance have an logic analyzer? If so, you could spy on the actual physical traffic and check if the data is already corrupt during sending or only during reading. I still think there could be a difference in actual data send between the i2ctransfer and your python program.

You have i2c transfer or smbus one? Which one should it be? Maybe this is the root cause?

I have no idea what you are asking.  I2ctransfer is a binary, presumably written in C.  Smbus is a Python library.
